# run an operator based on a pre-existing button or operator

Tags: python, scripting, drivers

I want to remove a driver with a custom property on the active pose bone.

```py
removeinc_x = bpy.ops.wm.properties_remove(data_path="active_pose_bone", property_name="increments_X")

if "FINISHED" in removeinc_x:
  bpy.context.active_pose_bone.driver_remove("rotation_euler", 0)
```

This is how I make sure it does happen^^

But how do I access an existing button without creating a new operator? I have no intentions on using real properties (due to anim player limitations) or a custom UI for now.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "access an existing button".  Could you expand on that?

Comment: @MartyFouts The X button to remove a custom property as an example. Rather than creating a remove button inside of Python.

Comment: You can't change the behavior of an existing button because all buttons do is invoke operators.

Comment: Is it possible to invoke a script if an operator is invoked?

Comment: The operator is a script.  You would have to edit its source code to change its behavior. Blender's Python API isn't really designed for the kind of substitution you'd like.